# 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/PROJECT_ID

Tags: python, python-3.x, blockchain, ethereum, web3py

I'm new to Web3.
I have created a project in infura.io.

```
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/PROJECT_ID'))
w3.isConnected() # True

cont = w3.eth.contract(address='my_contract_address', abi = my_abi)
cont.all_functions() # working well, return all functions inside contract

cont.funtions.get_info().call
```

after the last line I get an error

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/PROJECT_ID
```

What does it means, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that infura allows only to connect 1 contract per project. So if you want to connect to another contract you need to open another project.